# Can we use single flatFileItemReader bean in multiple steps running in parallel in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a single file with list of exchanges. I am doing different processing on the exchanges in different steps which runs in parallel.

Can I use same instance of flatFileItemReader or I should create separate bean for each step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From javadoc

> A FlatFileItemReader **is not thread safe** because it maintains state in
>   the form of a ResourceLineReader. Be careful to configure a
>   FlatFileItemReader using an appropriate factory or scope so that it is
>   not shared between threads.

Comment: so it means I should not use same bean, instead create a separate bean ?